# Meta Qustions length

Tags: discussion

I tried to ask a question in Meta, and I got the following error:

In red:
**

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> It does not meet our quality standards.**

I assume it's length related, but can the message be more specific?
Plus: My question, is relatively short, and I need to blow it up with nothing in order to ask it.

p.s.: that's the original question in meta [cycling or Bicycling?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/cycling-or-bicycling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like yes it was probably too short. Perhaps a general question calling for people to list tag synonyms would be better.