# cycling or Bicycling?

Tags: discussion

What of these should we keep?
Both?

That mainly goes for Tags

I know you go cycling with your bicycle, but what should the tags have? both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags should be synonymized and merged [bicycling](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bicycling) -> [cycling](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycling)

Comment: Do you think [biking] would go in there as well? Biking could refer to mountain biking or dirt biking. [Biking] itself would be a bad tag because of how ambiguous it would be.

Comment: @corsiKa Yes. dirt biking/motor biking should tagged [tag:dirt-biking] or [tag:motor-biking]

Comment: So what about the [biking] tag - banned, and make it clear to be more specific?

Comment: @corsiKa merging it into cycling will effectively ban it (all questions tagged [tag:biking] will be tagged [tag:cycling].

Comment: that's true - but biking is commonly used to mean dirt biking and mountain biking, for which cycling doesn't apply.

Comment: right, they will end up editing to retag their questions when it gets retagged cycling :P